# How to write Regex pattern to extract output from SOX info in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string (output from sox --info command):

```
Input File     : 'C:\Users\source\repos\dotnetcore\audio\1000.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:05:11.64 = 13743363 samples = 23373.1 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 27.5M
Bit Rate       : 706k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

I need to extract the file path (without the single quote), channels, sample rate etc.

I have a method where I pass in the whole string (the output) and the property I want to extract. Like this:

```
private static string Extract(string inputStr, string property)
        {
            string pattern = string.Format(@"\s+{0}\s+: '?(.*)\r\n", property);
            Match result = Regex.Match(inputStr, pattern);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return result.Groups[1].Value;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

This almost returns what I need, except for the last single quote in the Input File. How do I not include that in the pattern

```
Extract(output, "Input File") //returns C:\Users\source\repos\dotnetcore\audio\1000.wav' --> How to remove the last single quote
Extract(output, "Channels") //returns 1 --> Good
Extract(output, "Sample Rate") // returns 44100 --> Good
```

I have tried these patterns also

```
\s+Input File\s+: '?(.*)'? //Still returns with the last single quote
\s+Input File\s+: '?(.*)'+ //This works for Input File but doesn't work for other properties
```

Comment: @RajeshG that works for Input File but doesn't work for Channels. I need one pattern that works for all the properties. If I do `\s+Channels\s+: '?(.*)'+?` it doesn't match anything.

Comment: I was going to update my comment. Use this and see - `\s+Input File\s+: '?(.*)('?)$` DEMO - https://regex101.com/r/9VT1vl/1

Comment: `{0}\s+:\s*'?(.+?)['|\n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Based on the original author’s comment and my not inspecting all the lines closely enough

\s+{0}\s*: '?([^\r\n']*)'?

Original:

\s+{0}\s+: '?([^\r\n']*)'?

This is because * is greedy--it will keep pulling as many characters as it can. Because the ? allows 0 or 1 characters, it doesn't stop the * from continuing to pull in characters.

Comment: In the input string, in Sample Encoding header there is no space after it. So there needs to be a small change in the regex pattern. `\s+{0}\s*: '?([^\r\n']*)'?`. This pattern will work for all headers

Comment: Thank you—I updated my answer to reflect that for others who come across this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following expression: `\s*(?<name>[^:]+?)\s*:\s*(?<value>('[^']+')|.+)`

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/w7b2oO/1

A couple of differences:

- `(?<name>...)` gives the capture group a name so that you can reference it by name instead of index
- `('[^']+')|.+)` makes captures values enclosed in a string (`'[^']+'`) or (`|`) without (`.+`)